# Access child definition of const in parent in php?

Tags: php, inheritance, eloquent

i want to do this:

```
namespace Ffix\Cmc\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
abstract class AbstractMshopModel extends Model
{
  protected $table = self::FFIX_TABLENAME;
}


namespace Ffix\Cmc\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class MshopProduct extends AbstractMshopModel
{
 const FFIX_TABLENAME = 'mshop_product';

}
```

but i get:

> Couldn't find constant
>   Ffix\Cmc\Model\AbstractMshopModel::FFIX_TABLENAME in
>   /var/www/html/myapp/app/Cmc/Model/AbstractMshopModel.php on line 16

now i get it, the const does not exist yet. But it does exist in the child. How can I explicitly access the child?

**EDIT**

basically I want to be able to do this:

SomeExternalScript.php

```
<?php

//access MshopProduct::$table from outside without creating the whole object for doing so
```

Comment: Well, I think you have inverted:  `FFIX_TABLENAME ` should be in AbstractMshopModel instead of AbstractMshopModel.

Comment: @felipsmartins He wants a different value of it for each subclass.

Answer (score 1):

Property initialization has to use constants that can be evaluated when the code is compiled, it can't depend on the specific object. If the value is to be determined dynamically, you have to use a constructor that assigns to the property.

And constants have to be defined before they can be used, so I don't think you can use one here at all. You should use a getter function that the subclasses must implement.

```
abstract class AbstractMshopModel extends Model
{
  protected $table;
  abstract static function getFFIXTablename();

  function __construct() {
    $this->table = static::getFFIXTablename();
}

class MshopProduct extends AbstractMshopModel
{
    const FFIX_TABLENAME = 'mshop_product';
    static function getFFIXTableName() {
        return FFIX_TABLENAME;
    }

}
```

Comment: it's really ugly i have to redefine `getFFIXTableName()` on each subclass. 

What if I give up on constant. Is there a way to do something like `abstract public $Ffix_tablename;` Or any other form that keeps the subclass clean

Comment: I don't think so, but maybe you can find something by googling abstract classes in php.

Comment: I thought about doing this:

`class MshopProduct extends AbstractMshopModel
{
  const FFIX_TABLENAME = 'mshop_product';
  protected $table = self::FFIX_TABLENAME;` it is retarded, but i dont come up with something simpler